# Sort excel and be able to revert to previous order after edits

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I manage a spreedsheet that has about 30 columns and around 140 rows. It is a manning roster, and there is a set order that it needs to be in by office. Sometimes I need to sort by date or some other factor. When I sort it and make edits, I then have to cut and paste the rows back together in the original order.

Is there a way to sort, make edits, and then put the rows back in the original order without cutting and pasting?

One work around would be to have a hidden column that numbers each row, and use that to put them back in order, but I am trying to find a way to do this without having hidden rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming there's no identifiable logic behind 'set order that it needs to be in by office'... 'a hidden column that numbers each row' is how this would be done. Sorry. Another workflow-based alternative would be to see if you could use a FILTER to do your work on the data rather than a SORT.

Comment: As @AlexM mentioned use the filter function on your headings. the filter function can be found in the DATA tab of the toolbar. Make sure your data has no blank rows otherwise it will not be captured in the filter.